# Sampling a Panda Data Frame with Where condition

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Data Frame which has fields ,

ID, is_Animal, is_cat, is_dog

1. ,0, 0, 0
2. ,1, 0, 0
3. ,1, 0, 0

So, in this example, Row 2, is Animal but is neither dog nor cat. Row 1, is Not at all an Animal. 80 % of data is like Row 1 ie a non Animal record. The ask is to eliminate a fraction of such rows.
Lets say we have 200 rows, ie 160 of rows are non animal and 40 of them are good records to be kept. Ask  is to remove a random 90% of non animal records but also has to keep the good records. Hence 16 out of 160 NonAmimal records and 40 Animal records would be there in output.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.concat` and `DataFrame.sample`:

```
df = pd.concat([
   df[df['is_Animal'].eq(0)].sample(frac=0.9), 
   df[df['is_Animal'].eq(1)]
], ignore_index=True)
```